# optimize a function in r ( Error in solve.default)

Tags: r

I have the following equation:

[image]  (1)

`Rp,t+1`= the return of the portfolio .. `fr` = free risk rate.. `rt+1`: the return of a strategy.
`beta` has the following expression:
`beta=x0+x1*A+ x2*B+ x3*C+x4*D`  (Estimated using Generalized Method of Moments (GMM) (1).
`A`,`B`,`C` and `D` are the risk factors related to `rt+1`.

My objective is to find the optimal values of `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and `x4` that maximize the utility function of the investor.

[image]

with `U(Rp,t+1;x)` is the investor utility
`x` is the vector of parameters to maximize
`Zt` presents the 4 risk factors.

The code is:

```
ret<-cbind(ret)  #ret= rt+1
factors<-cbind(A,B,C,D)

func<-function(x,ret,factors) {
df <- data.frame(A=factors$A*x[1],B=factors$B*x[2],C=factors$C*x[3], D=factors$D*x[4])
H<-as.matrix(factors)
HH<-matrix(H,179,4)
m <- gmm(ret~., data=df, HH)
b<- coef(m)
beta<- b[1]+b[2]*factors$A+b[3]*factors$B+b[4]*factors$C+b[5]*D
beta=cbind(beta)

r=RF+beta*ret  #equation (1)
#Annual Sharpe ratio of the portfolio
averp<-mean(r)*12 
sigmap<-sqrt(12)*sd(r)
Sharpe<-averp/sigmap

#Calculating utility
u<-1/nrow(r)*sum((1+r)^(1-5)/(1-5))
obj<-u
result <- list(obj=obj,u=u,beta=beta,r=r,averp=averp,sigmap=sigmap,Sharpe=Sharpe)
return(result)
}

#Catching the obj from the function    
Final<-function(x,ret,factors){
bra<-func(x,ret,factors)
#print(bra$obj)
return(-bra$obj)
}
p<-optim(par = c(0,1,2,3),Final,method="Nelder-Mead",ret=ret,factors=factors)
bra<-func(x=p$par,ret=ret,factors=factors)
```

When I run the code, I get the following errors:
 for p -->

```
Error in solve.default(crossprod(hm, xm), crossprod(hm, ym)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[2,2] = 0
```

for bra -->

```
Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I am would be veryy grateful if you could help me on this ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would write a unit test for your func function. You can use `browser()` to step through it.

Put ret and factors into a data frame. `df <- data.frame(ret, A=factors$A*x[1], ...)`

Then run `m <- gmm(ret~., data=df); beta <- coef(m)`